# Install Github Python Package in R Reticulate

Tags: python, r

I'm trying to install the `magpie_python` package from github in an `R` environment, but I am running into numerous errors using traditional reticulate methods. None of them are working. I've not seen anything about installing github packages with reticulate yet so any help would be awesome.

Whenever I run the line

```
py_run_string("import magpie_python.attributes.generators.composition.ElementalPropertyAttributeGenerator")kd
```

I get a ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

Any help in figuring this out would be great